# Multiple event for segmented regression?

Tags: time-series, segmented-regression

Is there any statistical methods like segmented regression for many(>3) events?

Recently, many policies in my field were introduced in a short period of time. 
I usually used segmented regression to identify policy effects, but there are usually only one to three events in segmented regression in my best knowledge.

I have to analysis the effects of policies which are more than three events. 
In that case, is there any proper statistical method?

ps. I think differences-in-differences(DID) is not proper for my model. The effects are probably mixed.